# MouseOver ContentPresenter XAML Style

Tags: xaml, styles, mouseover, markup

I need to change colour of mouseover/pointover of content presenter but my style does not work.

Someone help me?

Thanks

```
<Style x:Key="Test" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ColorTest}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ColorTest}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible.  Visual States are published by specific controls, and `ContentPresenter` represents something that could be any kind of control or arbitrarily complex tree of elements.

You can use the subsections in [Control Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970773(v=vs.100).aspx) to get an idea of which Visual States are valid for each control, but as you see these are specific for the control in question, and not every state is always supported.

Your style could be amended to use Triggers, such as `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">`, but then you could only provide setters for properties of `ContentPresenter`, and `Foreground` is not one of those.

**Update**

However, as `TextBlock.Foreground` is an attached property, you can make the Trigger solution work in your specific example, and including complex control contents.  Please note this won't work for all properties however.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate">
            <ContentPresenter />
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Template="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}" Content="Test" />
</Grid>
```